# Apply CSS to certain list items

Tags: html, css, xslt

**Problem:** In the continuation of the solution provided by @potame in my previous question [Table of contents XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921026/table-of-contents-xsl), I would like to know if there's someway of not applying the CSS style to certain list items. The CSS provided was the following:

```
<style>
    body {
       text-align: justify;
    }
    ol, ul {
       counter-reset: item;
    }
    li {
       display: list-item;
       list-style-type: none;
    }
    li.chapter::before {
       content: "";
    }  
    li:before {
       content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
       counter-increment: item
    }
</style>
```

Following the reasoning of the table of contents also provided by @potame in the previous question,I've made the XSL template for processing the chapters, sections, subsections and subsubsections:

```
<xsl:template match="t:chapter">
    <li class="chapter">
    <h2>
       <a name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="t:title"/></a>
    </h2>
    <br/>
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::t:title)]"/>
    </ol>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:section">
    <li>
        <a name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="t:title"/></a>

    <br/>
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::t:title)]"/>
    </ol>
    </li>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:subsection">
    <li>
        <a name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="t:title"/></a>

    <br/>
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::t:title)]"/>
    </ol>
    </li>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:subsubsection">
    <li>
        <a name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="t:title"/></a>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::t:title)]"/>
    </li>    

</xsl:template>
```

And the following is the template for processing lists and paragraphs, that can appear in the content:

```
<xsl:template match="list:ol">
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list:ul">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>           
    </ul>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list:li/p:p">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>                           
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:p">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>           
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is, when I have list items in the content, HTML result appears like this:

```
Chapter 1
   1.1. Motivation

        ...some text...

        Example list:

        1.1.0.1. text
        1.1.0.2. tex
        1.1.0.3. text
        1.1.0.4. text
```

And the desired result in HTML is this:

```
Chapter 1
   1.1. Motivation

        ...some text...

        Example list:

        1. text
        2. text
        3. text
        4. text
```

Which basically means I want "normal ordered lists" instead of appearing like it was a subsubsubsection or something...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use  counter-reset: item;  on the the list you want and then start counting again - counter-increment: item

Comment: Ok, but where do I write that? inside the <style> element?

Comment: Yes, try this - li:before { counter-reset: item; counter-increment: item; content: counters(item) ;}

Comment: But as you can see in my code above, I already have a li:before for the numbering of sections, subsections and subsubsections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to set classes to all `<li>` related to your toc, and apply specific CSS styles to them (similarly to what I have done on the chapter). It will help you refine the styles to be applied.
Assuming you set in your XSLT `class="tocentrynumbered"` attribute on all `<li>`s related to a section, subsection, and so on, you can use the following modified CSS:

```
body {
     text-align: justify;
}
ol, ul {
     counter-reset: item;
}
li.chapter::before {
     content: "";
}  
li.tocentrynumbered {
     display: list-item;
     list-style-type: none;
}
li.tocentrynumbered:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Therefore it won't affect the other list items you use in the document.